# Laser book for physics GRE

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser, free-electron-lasers

The recent physics GRE exams have some questions on lasers. Does anyone know of a good  book which goes briefly through different types of lasers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was studying for the physics GRE I used the book [Conquering the Physics GRE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108409563) by Kahn and Anderson.

There are laser questions, but usually there will probably just be one question. There is a section in this book that covers the basics of what you need to know for the various laser types. I don't think you need anything beyond what is covered in this book. If your particular test happens to be "laser heavy", then I am sure the questions are expecting you to pull your knowledge from other physics topics, not just whether or not you know certain facts about laser types.

Additionally they give great advice for taking this specific test, provide great review, and excellent practice problems / tests.

Generally you should go back and review your text books from your classes as well. The test is probably being administered soon though, so I don't know how reasonable this is.

Answer (score 1):

For a brief overview, I can recommend the RP Photonics encyclopedia article on lasers with lots of links to more details on specific laser types:
https://www.rp-photonics.com/lasers.html.

This is probably the most comprehensive laser encyclopedia with articles and tutorials on an incredible range of laser related topics. Plus it's free.